# What looks to be wrong with this DirectX renderred model where you can only see the inside walls but the outer ones are transparent?

Tags: c++, graphics, windows-phone-8, directx, rendering

This has been surprisingly difficult to diagnose for whatever reason, but I figure someone here will be able to tell what's wrong really quickly.

To me, it looks like the polygons are being drawn with counterclockwise winding when they should have clockwise winding, that is, they are facing inwards and not outwards. I'm wondering if there's another way (other than creating redundant polygons) to make directx fill polygons on both sides (front and back).

Here are multiple screenshots of the rendered model (it's an elk toy):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For comparison, another model renders correctly and looks like this:

[image]

Thank you for taking a look

Comment: It almost looks to me like you don't have depth testing working properly. It looks like parts of the model that should be behind others, aren't. Can you provide screenshots from other angles? Without knowing how it's meant to look it's tricky to tell what's up.

Comment: Yes I can, I had that thought too, but I don't know much about DirectX's Z-buffering. I'll provide more screenshots. One moment. EDIT: Done

Comment: Since it looks like it's a winding issue, why can't you just reverse the winding?

Comment: I'm using assimp to load in my models. So I'm loading in models with arbitrary winding. It would be hard to programmatically determine if the model has the correct winding, so the CullMode solution listed below seems like the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Adam Miles said, it could very well be the lack of **Depth Testing**. The following is a link for Fixed-Function pipeline depth testing: [Z Buffer](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/z_buffer.html)

Depending on the version of DirectX you are using, you are going to have to set it up differently. Ultimately, you enable depth testing in HLSL like this:

```
ZEnable = true;
```

If you are using the fixed-function pipeline, then you will have to set a device render state:

```
dev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);
```

**However**, if it is because of the triangle "winding" aka **Cull mode**, you can change it in an HLSL shader like this:

```
CullMode = none; // Where Cullmode can be none, ccw, or cw
```

Again, if you are using the fixed-function pipeline, you can set a device render state as demonstrated here:

```
dev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);
//D3DCULL_NONE, D3DCULL_CCW or D3DCULL_CW
```

Setting the *cullmode* to none will cause both sides to be drawn. I'm quite sure one of those two issues are what you are experiencing judging by those screenshots. Goodluck!

Comment: This sounds like exactly what will solve my problem but I'm fairly new to HLSL and since I'm not using the fixed-function pipeline I have to go with the HLSL solution. However apparently you can only change CullMode in a technique and I don't really understand how to use those. Once I figure it out (the documentation online is comically bad), I'll mark this as the answer if it works (which I think it will). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright, sounds good. Indeed, HLSL doesn't have the greatest documentation, but i'll post up some nice sources.

Comment: @Nico I'm pretty sure this was the first one I ever learnt from. Its quite in depth and I think you'll find it very useful. Here you go:http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/first-shader. Don't worry about the template, just worry about the code. Its a beatiful tutorial.

Comment: That is a good tutorial, but does it only apply to XNA? I think you can still use techniques but I fear that the CullMode terminology has changed. Do you know of anywhere that I can learn about this feature? I honestly can't find any good sort of documentation.

Comment: @Nico Nono don't worry. It hasn't changed. And the shaders are written in HLSL, so while the tutorial is coupled with XNA, the shader code is completely independent. In DirectX 11 the constants may have slightly different names, but the idea remains the exact same. What version of DirectX are you using? The problem is that when it came to shaders, because of the lack of documentation, I had to gather bits and pieces of information from around the web for both the  shader itself and compilation/use. I'll keep a look out and let you know when I find a good one.

Comment: Hmm. So I took a break for a while (getting ready to go on vacation), but I'm confused as to why this isn't working. I put the following in my vertex shader, but I don't really know if it's actually being called: technique NoCull
{
    pass Pass1
    {
  CullMode = none;
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0 main();
    }
}

Comment: @Nico Can you show the code where you actually call the shader?

Comment: Yes. This has been an extremely frustrating experience. I feel like all things technique/effects11 is 'deprecated by neglect'. That means, they don't update or enhance the docs in any way so it's pretty much living hell to use. Judging by the Visual Studio 3d Starter Kit sample (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Visual-Studio-3D-Starter-455a15f1) you're supposed to do it like my next comment shows. But that just leaves me with a black model (the pixel shader seems to be disabled). I'm going to keep debugging but wow, the amount of time I've spent on this is getting sad.

Comment: HRESULT ModelRenderer::SetRasterizerState()
{
 // so mesh triangles always show, don't cull
    CD3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC d3dRas(D3D11_DEFAULT);
    d3dRas.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
    d3dRas.MultisampleEnable = true;
    d3dRas.AntialiasedLineEnable = true;

    m_d3dDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&d3dRas, &m_rasterizerState);
    m_d3dContext->RSSetState(m_rasterizerState.Get());

 return S_OK;
}

Comment: Can you send your full shader as well?

Comment: Of course. Thanks again for helping me out.

Vertex Shader: http://sdrv.ms/16MRJkX
Pixel Shader: http://sdrv.ms/16MRFS7

Comment: I got it hammered out. The normals were inward facing so when I disabled culling everything looked black. That was an easy fix and everything looks good now. Thanks for your help!